# Multidimensional scaling using Python

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-visualization, python, multidimensional-scaling

I have 6,000 points for which I have all pairwise distances in a distance matrix. I want to get an idea whether these data were generated by a mixture of Gaussian distributions so I'm trying to get a visualization. I am trying to apply multidimensional scaling in 2 dimensions using sklearn in Python.

I have four questions:

1. In all the examples I found, the number of points were very limited (around 20). Is it possible to apply MDS with 6,000 points?
2. If not, is there any way I can get a better idea whether my data were generated by a mixture of Gaussians? (I want to cluster this data using GMM.)
3. sklearn uses the function [manifold.MDS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html). One of the parameters of this function is 'random state'. What does it represent?
4. In [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_mds.html), the matrix used (X_true) has dimension 20x2. Shouldn't MDS take a distance matrix (i.e., a square matrix)?

Comment: There in the example, the data are generated and used to compute the matrix of distances.

Comment: It is possible to do MDS on 6000x6000 matrix, but it will take time (especially nonmetric MDS).

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. -- 3. Don't provide any random_state, default value is good enough. 4. Already answered by @ttnphns.

Comment: There are many different types of MDS algorithms. Take a look of those algorithms listed in wikipedia page for "nonlinear dimensinality reduction". Many of them can be applied on large distance matrix.